# How to display facebook post on website using php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fetch-api

I am trying to fetch my facebook page post to my website.so I used php for this.But I get an error

> Warning:
>   file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/mypageid/feed?access_token=myacesstokenE&fields=id,message,picture,link,name,description,type,icon,created_time,from,object_id&limit=5):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\Techtonic-website-demo\php\index.php on line 320

i replace my token and page id with text for security purpose

How can i solve this error

here is the code

```
 echo "<h1 class='page-header'>{$page_title}</h1>";
 $fb_page_id = "379175886256657";
 $profile_photo_src = "https://graph.facebook.com/{$fb_page_id}/picture?type=square";
 $access_token = "989164651468950|vH6SI6S8xD0zOZGjFew1ttlx9IE";
 $fields = "id,message,picture,link,name,description,type,icon,created_time,from,object_id";
 $limit = 5;
 $json_link = "https://graph.facebook.com/{$fb_page_id}/feed?access_token={$access_token}&fields={$fields}&limit={$limit}";
 $json = file_get_contents($json_link);
 $obj = json_decode($json, true);
 $feed_item_count = count($obj['data']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably, Facebook API disable file_get_contents. You should use curl to get json from Facebook API. View example code:

```
$fb_page_id = "379175886256657";
$profile_photo_src = "https://graph.facebook.com/{$fb_page_id}/picture?type=square";
$access_token = "989164651468950|vH6SI6S8xD0zOZGjFew1ttlx9IE";
$fields = "id,message,picture,link,name,description,type,icon,created_time,from,object_id";
$limit = 5;
$json_link = "https://graph.facebook.com/{$fb_page_id}/feed?access_token={$access_token}&fields={$fields}&limit={$limit}";

$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $json_link); 
$json = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);

$obj = json_decode($json, true);
var_dump($obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without specific approval from Facebook, you cannot use an App Token for Pages. Try with a Page Token instead: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/